# Python/Py2neo: weakref exception

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I create relationships using Py2neo in the following way:

```
article = graph.merge_one("Article", "id", aid)
article2 = graph.merge_one("Article", "id", aid2)
graph.create_unique(Relationship(article, "RELATED", article2))
```

But I get the following error message:

```
KeyError: 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/63'
Exception ignored in: <function WeakValueDictionary.__init__.<locals>.remove at 0x7f8ef4116e18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/or/env/lib/python3.4/weakref.py", line 108, in remove
del self.data[wr.key]
```

Comment: Please can you supply a full stack trace

Comment: @NigelSmall Thanks, but this is full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you've hit this bug:
https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/391

If so, this is fixed in 2.0.6.

Comment: I have upgraded to 2.0.6, but there is still the same error